# rename file extension in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

newfilenames=[newfilenames.replace('hpp','h')for newfilenames in filenames]
print(newfilenames)

Comment: you're appending a string there. You create a tuple by using brackets like so: `newfilenames.append((old_name, new_name))`. Check the answer of @OD1995

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
newfilenames = []
for x in range(len(filenames)):
    old_name = filenames[x]
    if old_name.endswith(".hpp"):
      new_name = old_name.replace('.hpp','.h')
    else:
      new_name = old_name;
    newfilenames.append((old_name, new_name))
print (newfilenames)
```

[image]

Comment: this will also rename `hpp.out` to `h.out`. You need to check for `.hpp` at the end of the name.

Comment: replace the if clause with `if filenames[x].endswith('.hpp')`

Comment: @wullxz, No need of `if` check.

Comment: @Austin after the last edit, yes

Comment: Thank you so much. This works and much simpler.